# Python - Expression generator to build list with 'and' before last item?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use python to take an array of names

```
['mary','lucy','beth','molly']
```

and construct a string like:

```
mary, lucy, beth and molly
```

Trying to do this in one line, and it looks like a generator expression may be the way to go.  Obviously I can easily get a list like "mary, lucy, beth, molly", but does anyone know how I can go about generating a string to include the 'and' before the final item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>>> x = ['mary','lucy','beth','molly']
>>> ', '.join(x[:-1]) + ' and ' + x[-1]
'mary, lucy, beth and molly'
```

There's no real need for a generator expression here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly slower but maybe interesting version:

```
names = ['mary', 'lucy', 'beth', 'molly']
last = len(names) - 1    

result = ""
for i in range(0, last):
    result += names[i] + ", "
result += "and " + names[last]

print(result) # or print result for python2
```

This results in 'mary, lucy, beth, and molly'. Note the oxford comma :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along those lines:

```
", ".join(array[:-1]) + " and " + array[-1]
```

Comment: `array` is a std module so perhaps not the best variable name..?

Comment: @thebjorn it's not a built-in, so unless the OP's importing it I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 0):

A different take using string formatting:

```
l = ['mary','lucy','beth','molly']

print "{} and {}.".format(", ".join(l[:-1]),l[-1])

mary, lucy, beth and molly.
```

Or pop if you are throwing the list away after:

```
print "{1} and {0}.".format(l.pop(-1),", ".join(l))
```

Comment: Destructive consumption of the list seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Dunes, why exactly, what is going to happen? I removed from the end of the list, what difference is that going to make?

Comment: The list won't be the same after the expression. Meaning you're stuffed if you still needed it. There's just no real reason to alter the contents of the list to make the string.

Answer (score 0):

and yet some more,

```
L = ['mary','lucy','beth','molly']
print(', '.join(L[:]).replace((", " + L[-1]), (" and " + L[-1]))) 
print("%s and %s" % (', '.join(L[:-1]), L[-1]))

mary, lucy, beth and molly
mary, lucy, beth and molly
```